# Could we able product apps and programs for AppleSilicon-Base processors with Intel-Base Processors?

Tags: swift

As we know Apple switched to **Apple-Silicon** Processors with new **M1** chip, I would like to know If our old **Intel** Based Apple devices (iMac, iMac Pro, MacPro, . . .) would be still able to build app's for new M1 or M2 . . . what is waiting for old devices in future? Because Intel CPU has deferent architect than Apple-Silicon! And would choosing **UIKit** or **SwiftUI** put effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still build apps for Apple Silicon on your Intel based machine. Simply select the ARM / Intel profile in Xcode and Xcode will build an universal binary file.